# Sharepoint task - approval

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

How to edit the task name? I have a list that requires approval. I have checked the settings and even the workflow but I can't find the correct field to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you use SharePoint Designer to create a workflow with task process?

If that’s the case, whether you use SharePoint 2010 platform or SharePoint 2013 platform?

If 2010, in the Start Approval Process action, click the "these users", type the "Title" for task name.

[image]

If you use 2013 platform, in the "start a task process" action, click "these users", type the "Task Title" for name.

[image]

Comment: If it helps, you can mark it as answer. Thanks for your understanding.